# on update maven project it removes the attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" in eclipse in .classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, classpath

The project description:

- Dynamic web project.
- Maven for dependencies i compile the project with eclipse default compilation. am not compiling project with
  maven.
- java 6 (mentioned in pom.xml that source and target as java
  6, but current installed version in eclipse is java 7).
- It is a web-application. I have use jsf, hibernate ,spring , spring-security in the project.

The below lines are from my ".classpath" file in eclipse for this project.

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

If i update maven, by right click on project , Maven - > update project. i find changes in the classpath.

```
 <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
```

the above line is missing. with out this my project is not running in tomcat in eclipse. 
am trying to run this project by selecting "run on server" option using keyboard shortcut "shift-alt-x R".

Earlier the same project was running. After updating the project from a newly installed SVN for this project am facing this issue. help me where to start finding the issue. Ask for more info if required, so that you can help me to sort this issue.

Part of stacktrace here,

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you import your project as existing maven project?

Comment: yes it is a maven project. only because of that am able to select "maven -> update project" option on right click over the project. I will add the actual issue and solution that arrived here as a answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a java version related issue. since this project has is dependent to a java project running in a server with java 6 we have downgraded the project from java 7 to java 6.

I have changed runtime, build path and pom.xml pointing to java 6. but, forgot to change in web.xml header endpoints.

Because of that , when updating the project, eclipse got struck up to find that this is a web project.

i.e,

From (java 7)

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
```

To (java 6)

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
```

After this change, on "maven-> update project"  i got the proper project setup.